# Наложение водяного знака в PIL

Tags: python

Имеется бот:
задача бота:
Пользователь отправляет первую фотографию на которую хочет наложить водяной знак. Далее отправляет второе изображение самого водяного знака. И далее бот отправляет пользователю первое фото с наложенным поверх водяным знаком (фото от пользователя номер два)

Первая картинка:
[image]

Далее загружаю изображение номер два(Водяной знак)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе получается вот такое изображение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ЖЕЛАЕМЫЙ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ НА ВЫХОДЕ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код снизу, какие параметры изменить и как это можно реализовать?

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=Groupuser.znak)
async def load_znak(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['znak'] = message.photo[2].file_id #Выбираем самое высокое разрешение

    photo = requests.get(URI_INFO + data['photo']) #Отправляем гет запрос и получае данные о фото
    photo_path = photo.json()['result']['file_path'] #Получаем путь файла
    photo_content = requests.get(URI + photo_path) #Отправляем гет запрос и получаем фото
    user_photo = Image.open(io.BytesIO(photo_content.content)).convert('RGBA') #Отправляем фото в буфер в байтах. Конвертируем в RGBA


    photo_z = requests.get(URI_INFO + data['znak'])
    photo_path_z = photo_z.json()['result']['file_path']
    photo_content_z = requests.get(URI + photo_path_z)
    user_photo_z = Image.open(io.BytesIO(photo_content_z.content)).resize((400,100)).convert('RGBA') #Указали размер водяного изображения
    user_photo_z.putalpha(100) #Указали прозрачность


    #Вставляем водяной знак
    width, height = user_photo.size #Берем размер первого фото
    transparent = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 0)) #Создаем новое изображение и указываем размер, координаты
    transparent.paste(user_photo, (0, 0)) #Вставляем наше первое фото, позиция 0,0
    position = 50, 200 #Позиция для водяного знака

    transparent.paste(user_photo_z, position, mask=user_photo_z) #Вставляем наш водяной знак и указываем прозрачность

    transparent.save('Watemark.png', format='png') #Сохраняем наш итоговый результат
    photo_send = open('Watemark.png', 'rb') #Открываем наш результат
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo_send)
    os.remove('C:\тг бот тест\photo\Watemark.png')
    await state.finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот функция для добавления watermark на изображение:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


def add_watermark(main_image: Image.Image, watermark: Image.Image, position: tuple) -> Image.Image:
    res = main_image.copy().convert('RGBA')
    watermark = watermark.convert('RGBA')

    x = np.asarray(watermark).copy()
    x[:, :, 3] = (100 * (np.sum(x[:, :, :3], axis=2) < 700)).astype(np.uint8)
    watermark = Image.fromarray(x)

    alpha = watermark.getchannel('A')
    crop = alpha.getbbox()
    watermark = watermark.crop(crop)

    res.alpha_composite(watermark, position)

    return res
```

Использование в вашем коде:

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=Groupuser.znak)
async def load_znak(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['znak'] = message.photo[2].file_id #Выбираем самое высокое разрешение

    photo = requests.get(URI_INFO + data['photo']) #Отправляем гет запрос и получае данные о фото
    photo_path = photo.json()['result']['file_path'] #Получаем путь файла
    photo_content = requests.get(URI + photo_path) #Отправляем гет запрос и получаем фото
    user_photo = Image.open(io.BytesIO(photo_content.content))


    photo_z = requests.get(URI_INFO + data['znak'])
    photo_path_z = photo_z.json()['result']['file_path']
    photo_content_z = requests.get(URI + photo_path_z)
    user_photo_z = Image.open(io.BytesIO(photo_content_z.content))

    position = 50, 200  # Позиция для водяного знака

    add_watermark(user_photo, user_photo_z, position).save('Watemark.png', format='png') #Сохраняем наш итоговый результат
    photo_send = open('Watemark.png', 'rb') #Открываем наш результат
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo_send)
    os.remove('C:\тг бот тест\photo\Watemark.png')
    await state.finish()
```